# Dynamic ROOT_URL for Meteor app being served from multiple subdomains

Tags: meteor

I have an app which runs on multiple subdomain (one per tenant). Works all good in development environment since I do not set value for `ROOT_URL` there.

But, when I deploy an app to production, Meteor asks me to set the `ROOT_URL` environment variable.

I can not set the value of `ROOT_URL` to a specific domain in the environment variable since app runs on multiple subdomains. What would be the best way for me to set the `ROOT_URL` value via code?

Please do suggest if there are any other better solutions.

Answer (score 1):

The variable only needs to be defined at the time the app starts, so you can easily build a multi-tenant environment by starting your application instances with a script like this:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

export PORT=3000
export ROOT_URL=https://domain1.example.com
node /path/to/your/app/bundle/main.js

export PORT=4000
export ROOT_URL=https://domain2.example.com
node /path/to/your/app/bundle/main.js

exit 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change environmental variables inside your code. You could do something like this.

```
Meteor.startup(function() {
    //do some logic...
    //...
    process.env.ROOT_URL = 'http://subdomain1.mydomain.com';
});
```

Edit: You could also try using the meteor cluster package which I think can do what you want. https://github.com/meteorhacks/cluster

Comment: I don't think this would work as the code above will only set one particular value for the ROOT_URL on startup while a user can access the app from any subdomain.

Comment: You could detect which server you are on with some logic during runtime, like lookup the hostname and then set ROOT_URL. Also I added the suggestion for using meteor cluster which I think will fit your use case.